# Verifying country code and remove 0 after country code if exist at input type tel html5

Tags: html, regex, tel

How can I verify that the user fills in the telefon number starting with +46 and not using a 0 after +46

- Like +46700401008 and not 0700401008.
- Also remove 0 if user fills in +460700401008.

I understand the type tel supports pattern which I understand uses Regex.. See below an example.

Enter your phone number:

Format: 123-456-7890

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `type="tel"`:

```
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"
       pattern="\+46\d{9}"
       required>
```